# should I reuse the cursor in the python MySQLdb module

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I'm writing a python CGI script that will query a MySQL database.  I'm using the MySQLdb module.  Since the database will be queryed repeatedly, I wrote this function....

```
def getDatabaseResult(sqlQuery,connectioninfohere):
    # connect to the database
    vDatabase = MySQLdb.connect(connectioninfohere)
    # create a cursor, execute and SQL statement and get the result as a tuple
    cursor = vDatabase.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
    except:
        cursor.close()
        return None
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return result
```

My question is...  Is this the best practice?  Of should I reuse my cursor within my functions?  For example.  Which is better...

```
def callsANewCursorAndConnectionEachTime():
    result1 = getDatabaseResult(someQuery1)
    result2 = getDatabaseResult(someQuery2)
    result3 = getDatabaseResult(someQuery3)
    result4 = getDatabaseResult(someQuery4)
```

or do away with the getDatabaseeResult function all together and do something like..

```
def reusesTheSameCursor():
    vDatabase = MySQLdb.connect(connectionInfohere)
    cursor = vDatabase.cursor()

    cursor.execute(someQuery1)
    result1 = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute(someQuery2)
    result2 = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute(someQuery3)
    result3 = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute(someQuery4)
    result4 = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The MySQLdb developer recommends building an application specific API that does the DB access stuff for you so that you don't have to worry about the mysql query strings in the application code. It'll make the code a bit more extendable ([link](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#using-and-extending)).

As for the cursors my understanding is that the best thing is to create a cursor per operation/transaction. So some `check value -> update value -> read value` type of transaction could use the same cursor, but for the next one you would create a new one. This is again pointing to the direction of building an internal API for the db access instead of having a generic `executeSql` method.

Also remember to close your cursors, and commit changes to the connection after the queries are done.

Your `getDatabaseResult` function doesn't need to have a connect for every separate query though. You can share the connection between the queries as long as you act responsible with the cursors.

Comment: Another small notice: in MySQLdb cursor creation does nothing with network requests to the DB, so it is cheap operation.

Comment: If you keep the connection, you presumably have to check whether it is still open (right?). Is this preferable over reconnecting?

Comment: @lucidbrot No, I think you can expect it to stay open, just like while you maybe be working with a file, you don't check after each line of code if it's still 'open',  rather, at a higher level you should catch the exceptions thrown if query is attempted on closed connection. those will happen before a 'commit' so it's safe to do it that way. if you'll need cleanup you can catch the exception in the function itself, clean up then bubble it up for high level to decide what to do about lost connection (like reconnect or exit)